# Enumerate all the properties of a hash object in javascript without using for in?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just learned from [this article](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers) by on github about javascript V8 engine code optimization

> For-in statements can prevent the entire function from being optimized
>   in a few cases.

One of the cases is when object is hash object, e.g:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'fdsfds',
    email: 'fdsfd@fds.com',
    password: 'fjdlsjfkdslfjds'
};
```

It is about one page reading in above link, chapter 5. For-in.

I wonder if there is any way to loop through a hash object without using

```
for(var key in hashTable)
```

for-in loop?

Comment: Re-read what he writes. Objects can be represented in the engine in multiple ways, one of them being a hash-table, another being a faster native struct. The engine defaults to fast mode, only de-optimising in cases he mentions. Also, he has a "workaround" part.

Comment: Yes, the work around is put the for-in loop in a separate function to minimize the impact. I am just asking if there is a way of not using for-in for looping hash table at all. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No, when he says "hash map", he means *internally represented as a hash map*, which *only* happens in specific cases, for instance if you have oddly named properties. Your example is not one of them. And again, he has a "workaround" section right at the end which mentions how to iterate over it.

Comment: I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/nettrinity/428jR/  It looks like mine is not "oddly". I am still bit confused about "hash table mode". It looks like the only difference is his oddly object using "-". Where I can find the definition about oddly named properties?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know it's a good way of doing or not but you can do something like bellow

```
Object.keys.forEach(function(key){
    //do your task
});
```

Comment: sounds interesting. let me try it

Comment: I think it should be Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key, value){ /// do you task })

Comment: no this is array foreach so it can't return the value of the object to get the object you have to do `obj[key]`.

Comment: @Mritunjay @NicolasS.Xu they way you have to call it is actually `Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function (key) {});` as `Object.keys` is a prototype function of `Object` itself and it needs the context to get the keys. See [MDN Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for further explanation :)

Comment: This is even slower by the way... Read Zirak's comments on the question.

Comment: Oh I just noticed you say it's faster in the answer, -1 for that and also for not answering the right question (again, see Zirak's comments). Please fix.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum and I didn't get not answering the right question, OP asked how can he loop on object in another way. And I answered that

Comment: OP thinks that the object in how question is a hash map when in fact it is not. On the other hand the object in your benchmark.. I'm on mobile but I'll try to leave a longer reply when I get to my computer. You can check my "How does Bluebird's..." Answer for more reading on dictionary mode and fast objects and more links.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum removed that point which tells that it is `faster` after checking here http://jsperf.com/javascript-for-in-vs-key-foreach, but I just checked once , & it is sometime tells slower also.